# Can someone please recommend me a good PyQt/PySide tutorial/book/video series?

Tags: python, pyqt

... or is Rapid GUI Development with PyQT everything that I'll ever need?

I went through some online and most of them are really outdated, most of the code does not work, or they are written terribly in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I liked the tutorial, "PyQt by example," available at this address: http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS47.html.  However, it may well be dated now.  It does the somewhat overplayed "todo list" app, but nonetheless, it was clear and illustrated things well.  It also provided a reasonable introduction to SqlAlchemy or Elixir, if I recall.

For open source frameworks, even one with so much scale and cross-platform punch, you can never really get "everything you'll ever need."  But the book you cited is still undoubtedly the best resource for learning PyQt, unless you're willing to look at C++ examples.  It's a bit encyclopedic, and certainly humorless, but it covers a lot of ground and does so in a way that's unlikely to be invalidated by updates to the library over time.

If anyone has other good recommendations, I'd enjoy hearing them, but I've looked too and the best ones are all reasonably dated (though I didn't find them too hard to get working).

Edit: Since it appears this question is getting some views, I thought I'd come back and add a few of what I found to be the most useful tutorials on PyQt.  Though they all come with some caveats, they all have enough substance to be of value:

1. PyCon 2011 Talks: Creating GUI Applications in Python Using QT (talk I and talk II); only caveat here is I can't find them-- have found slightly more than 100 pycon 2011 talks online, mostly mirroring blip.tv, but these don't seem to be anywhere...
2. Very good intro to core signals and slots ideas:
   http://www.harshj.com/2009/05/14/pyqt-signals-slots-and-layouts-tutorial/; somewhat short and conceptual but useful.
3. Pycon 2009 talk in Italy with quite comprehensive pdf tutorial for qt (link to pdf) 
   http://chaos.troll.no/~dboddie/Python/PyConTre_Italia_2009/PyCon_Italia_2009_PyQt_for_Desktop_and_Embedded_Devices.pdf
4. Command Prompt published what amounts to a pyqt book online.  I found it very helpful and it's worth consulting with specific questions at least, but it's very old (2001): http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/?page=pyqtbook
5. Pretty good intro to specific widgets' uses, but seems to have withheld more interesting knowledge for a 'pro-version' ebook.  Still was semi-helpful: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/
6. Apparently the eric-ide for python provides integration with qtdesigner and their site hosts a tutorial looking at the two together, which appears to be in depth though I only just discovered it: http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/tutorials/MiniBrowser/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the PyQt by example and found it honestly a bit hard and definitely dated. Looks like Rapid GUI Development with PyQT is still the king.

Comment: In any case, I ordered the book and it should be here tomorrow!